# How to convert a character from a file into an ascii integer into an array?

Tags: c, arrays, io

I am attempting to put a list of characters AND integers into an array of just integers. The file.txt looks like:

```
 a 5 4 10 
 4 10 a 4
```

In the array I want the values to come out as {97,5,4,10,4,10,97,4}
This is part of my code:

```
int * array = malloc(100 * sizeof(int));
FILE* file;
int i=0;
int integer = 1;
file=fopen(filename,"r");
while (fscanf(file,"%d",&integer) > 0)
{
    array[i] = integer;
    i++;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that, at first read, your while condition will exit because first element in the file is a char and [fscanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/) won't interpret it as an integer, returning 0. I would suggest, if you are sure that your separator is a space, reading a string (it will automatically stop at space) and convert read value to int with [strtol](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/?kw=strtol).

Something like:

```
int * array = malloc(100 * sizeof(int));
FILE* file;
int i=0;
char tmp[2], *pEnd;
file=fopen("./test.txt","r");
while (fscanf(file,"%s",tmp) > 0)
{
    if( !(array[i] = strtol(tmp, &pEnd,10)))
         array[i] = tmp[0];
    i++;
}
```

Note that I assumed that you'll have no integer bigger than one digit (`tmp` array size) and that I check `strtol` response for detecting non integer chars.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that what you want to do is use `fscanf("%s", some_string)` since numerics can be received as strings but strings cannot be received as numerics. Then with each input, you need to decide if the string is actually numeric or not, and then derive the value you want to place into the array accordingly.